# Google Maps API : Display a digit in a GMarker

Tags: javascript, google-maps

How can I display a digit inside the GMarker ?
I used title, but it is only on rollover like title on links or image.

Do you have any idea how I can do that ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's two ways to do it.

The old way is to create or obtain images for markers with each number and use them as custom icon images. There are several sets listed [here](http://mapki.com/wiki/Icon_Image_Sets) or you can use one of the services listed there to create your own, or draw your own with an image editor. Save the resulting images to your own webspace, don't try to use the services dynamically because they occasionally fail.

The new way is to use the [LabeledMarker](http://gmaps-utility-library.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/labeledmarker/) extension which creates things that work something like Google markers but allow you to put text onto the marker dynamically. (Hint: works quite nicely with [MapIconMaker](http://gmaps-utility-library.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/mapiconmaker/), like [this](http://econym.org.uk/gmap/example_iconmaker.htm).)

Answer (score 1):

You can create custom markers with [mapicon Factory](http://www.cartosoft.com/mapicons/).  Select the **Characters** radio button and pick a character type, and then click the **Numbers** checkbox.  Dismiss the ad and you will see the markers.